Jackson - Don't allow field in JSON response
I have a Spring MVC app with DTO/Entity representations of a User. Users can be created through an API. The password is hashed and saved in a database. We do NOT want to include the hashed password in the API response.
I tried to include @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY) on the password, but the password isn't getting included when converting the DTO to the Entity using ObjectMapper. How can I make it so the password isn't in the response, but does get included when converting from UserDto to User.
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Date createDate;

    @Id
    @Column
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    
    public void setUsername(final String username) { this.username = username; }
    
    @Column
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    
    public void setPassword(final String password) { this.password = password; }

    @Column
    public String getCreateDate() { return createDate; }
    
    public void setCreateDate(final String createDate) { this.createDate = createDate; }

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    private String username;
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Date createDate;
}

public class UserController {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public User addUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = userService.add(mapper.convertValue(userDto, User.class));
        return mapper.convertValue(user, UserDto.class);
    }
}

// Request body
{
    "username": "myuser",
    "password": "mypassword"
}

// Desired successful response
{
    "username": "myuser"
    "createdDate": "2024-04-05 00:00:00"
}


Please also include User class

@samabcde I updated it to include the User class.

I prefer for problems to not exist to begin with rather than having to solve them. So I would prefer to have a DTO with a password and a DTO without a password. Use the right one where appropriate. You are already making the smart decision of not exposing entities in your REST endpoints, so just complete the journey. Don't have a single chance of making a mistake and exposing the password there either, by not having it in the object at all.

@Gimby Yeah I have done that in other projects. I prefer modeling the entity, rather than modeling each request/response, but it does make it a bit more foolproof.

Create your own UserSerializer (class that extends JsonSerializer, such when serialize() is called it only serializes the value that you need.

Another way is not using convertValue to do the conversion between User<>UserDto. As I suppose Json configuration is external facing. Internal conversion should not be coupled to that.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I think I'm going to go with separate DTO for request and response. It's more classes, but overall simpler and fewer annotations.

Why? Just use @JsonIgnore lol. Easy peasy.

@SledgeHammer @JsonIgnore prevents both serialization and deserialization, so it would never get to the controller.

@Dannenberger nah, you put it on the getter or setter (as appropriate for a particular use case) and set read/write access on the field with @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) (or READ_ONLY).

Either way, passing a password in plain text in JSON is a terrible idea :).
